# How to pass the repeat count to x command in GDB

Tags: gdb

The x command can examine memory in GDB. Like

```
x/4xg 0x60400
```

Now I am going to define my own x comand which examines memory with specified repeat count, like:

```
define myXCommand
    set var &repeatCount=$arg0
    x/(???)xg 0x60400
end
```

I have tried many ways to pass the variant repeatCount to x command, but I failed finally. My problem is how to pass the repeat count to x command? Appreciated very much if anyone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convenience variable can be used in most expressions, but the `x` command only allows the repeat count to be a string of digits, not an arbitrary expression.

What you can do is use the [`eval`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Output.html#index-eval) command, which does a `printf` on its arguments and then runs the result as a command.

```
define myXCommand
    set var $repeatCount=$arg0
    eval "x/%dxg 0x60400", $repeatCount
end
```

Comment: This is what I want. Thank you very much for your answer.